# jQuery tooltip - custom content does not display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I've followed the documentation and am trying to display a custom tooltip with jQuery UI tooltips.

```
var element = $('#customspan');

element.tooltip(
content: function () {
    return 'Custom Span Tooltip'
};
```

However, the custom content is not being displayed. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/obiwanzamora/61d2orLd/)

Comment: There's a typo in your fiddle: you need to pass the initialization options as an object. Also, you need to include a title attribute (it doesn't necessarily have to have a value, just exist), since you haven't specified a default selector. Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/7gsdt49v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. After some digging I discovered that the [Bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) was overriding JQuery UI which was why I was getting inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax is incorrect. It must be like this:

```
element.tooltip({
    content: function () {
        return 'Custom Span Tooltip'
    }
});
```

Maybe it's here your problem

Comment: Thanks - problem still persists unfortunately.

Comment: You need to specify the items like in the documentation: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify content you should also specify the `items` property of the elements you want to have the custom content, instead of showing the `title` attribute by default.

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function () {
       return 'Custom Span Tooltip'
    },
    items: '#customspan'
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea7xrjmn/1/)

Comment: Thanks - that JSFiddle still does not display the custom content though?

Comment: Does for me? Hover on the second element and it appears below